# How does Mal know where to find Robert Michael Fischer?

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

In *[Inception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception)* Cobb tells Ariadne not to show him the architectural plans so that Mal will not appear in the dream.

Still, Mal appears at the end of the movie and kills Fischer who is standing in front of the vault.

How did Mal appear in the vault room if Cobb/Mal doesn't know the architecture of the dream?

Answer (score 20):

At the point in time that we see Mal appear in the room with Fischer, we see her through a gun-sight aimed by Cobb.  She appears to drop into the room from above.  Mal is just a projection of Cobb, so she does not need to break into the room by knowing the maze around the vault.

Cobb by his very presence and line of sight of the room, aided by the gun sight is projecting Mal into the dream - at the worst possible point yet again, just as their goal is about to be achieved.

Answer (score 5):

Ariadne dóes tell Dom the secondary entry when the announcing music for the upcoming kick begins and the plan has to change due to less remaining time.

Comment: Ariadne does tell that there is another quicker path, but doesn't give the details to him - he says something like "tell them" - directing Ariadne to give the details to Eames, Fisher and Saito